# Would core data be a good choice?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

I am trying to write an application that will access, and change, entries in a user's calendars. The changes are driven by fairly complex rules, that the user can define.

My question, before I spend too much time developing, is whether I should go with core data. A lot of the model will be handled by core data, but I will need to access a lot of stored info and then change it. Would this be a problem with core data?

It would help if I had a better understanding of core data, but at this point I do not :(  Could someone comment on the possibility to perform changes on the model data, when using core data? I'd hate to be a few months into the development, and discover I made the wrong choice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recently released [WWDC media collection](https://developer.apple.com/videos/) contains an audio presentation from 2005 when the Core Data framework was released as part of the OS X frameworks. The presentation covers Core Data's primary goals, design principles and architecture. It also discusses a set of sample applications (the recipy apps). The collection is available through iTunesU. It is worthwhile to listen to to grasp the framework's working principles.

I've been working with Core Data for a while now. I find it easy to work with, well integrated into Xcode, stable and so far has been a true contributor to my productivity. It offers various storage options for your data (binary, XML - very easy to work with during development - and SQLite), very decent tool support, easy model migration for small changes, complex migration available for major model changes with some extra effort.

You will have to be aware of the fact that Core Data is NOT a RDBMS nor a RDBMS mapping tool. It is an object graph and persistence framework, which is a different thing. If you ignore this fact, Core Data might give you performance penalties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link @Roger! I will listen to the presentation. I'll also continue to read up on the ADC docs of Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

Making schema changes isn't harder with CoreData than with most other data frameworks. CoreData can handle many simple changes to your data model [on its own](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1). When it can't figure out the right thing to do, [you can write custom migrations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1).

In my experience, CoreData usually makes data-intensive apps easier to write and maintain, with a very slight loss in flexibility that you usually won't miss.

Comment: Do you have an indication of the kind of flexibility I **might** loose out on? I must say that in general, your answer and the one from @roger are making CD look like a good option for me.